# Set request object as JAXBElement using Java

Tags: java, jaxb

I'm trying to set one request object using java. But, its asking that it accepts only JAXBElement object, I'm not sure how to create request object like that. My request object has set of setters & getters. Here is my code

```
LOSRequest losRequest = new LOSRequest();
losRequest.setData(request);
```

Possible solutions: setData(javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement)

Here is LOSRequest

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType(javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType(name = "LOSRequest", propOrder = {"data", "requestid", "userCtx"})
public class LOSRequest {
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementRef(name = "data", namespace = "http://to.service.los/xsd", type = javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement.class)
protected javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement<java.lang.String> data;
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementRef(name = "requestid", namespace = "http://to.service.los/xsd", type = javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement.class)
protected javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement<java.lang.String> requestid;
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementRef(name = "userCtx", namespace = "http://to.service.los/xsd", type = javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement.class)
protected javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement<los.service.to.xsd.LOSUserContext> userCtx;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is `LOSRequest`?

Comment: Please indent your code. Please use `import`s to shorten the class/annotation names.

Answer (score 0):

Use annotated members:

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementRef;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "LOSRequest", propOrder = {"data", "requestid", "userCtx"})
public class LOSRequest {

    @XmlElementRef(name = "data", namespace = "http://to.service.los/xsd", type = JAXBElement.class)
    protected String data;

    // Getter/Setter
}
```

Then you should be able to do

```
LOSRequest l = new LOSRequest();
l.setData("foo");
```

**Edit:**

This is different from your code where the members are wrapped:

```
protected JAXBElement<String> data;
```

This wrapping of course makes it impossible to set a simple `String` as the value of the `data` member.

Comment: What change did you made? I don't see anything?

Comment: LOSRequest is generated as JAR, I can't change it.. I should only use it

Comment: Then you will have to use a `JAXBElement<String>` as the argument.

Comment: I have a Model class called "Request", where I'm setting all the setters & now, I just want to convert this object as JAXBElement..